# A Second Reduction

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Sparkle and shimmer, you're losing a grand.
Refuse and you'll find that steeped leaves I demand.
Measure the liquid and then you are gone.
Fatless and weightless the east end is done.
Burning and brightened you call out: "Left, left!"
It just isn't right, me alone and bereft.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer is:

> **GLITTER** -> Sparkle and shimmer
> **LITTER** -> Not refUse, but rather REFuse (garbage)
> **LITER** -> A measure of liquid
> **LITE** -> Fatless and weightless (diet foods often labeled "lite")
> **LIT** -> Burning and brightened, like a fire
> **IT** -> "It" isn't right
> **I** -> Me, alone and bereft

The reduction is as follows:

> **GLITTER** -> *You're losing a grand* = **G** as in "I got 50 G"
> **LITTER** -> *steeped leaves I demand* = tea = **T**
> **LITER** -> *you are gone* = ..."**R**" gone
> **LITE** -> *east end is done* = rightmost letter = **E**
> **LIT** -> *you call out: "Left, left!"* = leftmost letter = **L**
> **IT** -> *just isn't right* = rightmost letter = **T**
> **I** -> **insert your favorite song about loneliness here**